# How to fix "No manual entry for gcc"?

Tags: macos, gcc, homebrew, manpage

I somehow lost the man pages for gcc and g++. I'm not sure where/what to look for. I'm pretty sure the man pages used to work some time ago. It also works on my Mac at work where I use roughly the same setup. Could it be a problem with brew? Or is it a bug in the XCode Command Line Tools?

Update: I just tried to re-install the XCode Command Line Tools. No luck.

```
~
✓  man gcc
No manual entry for gcc

~
✗  which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

~
✓  gcc --version
Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.1.0
Thread model: posix
```

Comment: You may want to try asking on Superuser as that site will probably have better help for issues involving tools

Comment: does man work for other things...

Comment: @GradyPlayer yes it does. It works with unrar which I installed using brew.

Comment: oh actually new XCODE doesn't really have gcc, gcc is only a symlink to clang try man clang

Answer (score 15, accepted):

gcc isn't installed anymore by Xcode, it really installs clang and calls it gcc

```
usxxplayegm1:~ grady$ which gcc
/usr/bin/gcc

usxxplayegm1:~ grady$ /usr/bin/gcc --version

Configured with: --prefix=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr --with-gxx-include-dir=/usr/include/c++/4.2.1
Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.38) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin13.0.2
Thread model: posix
```

you need `man clang`

I thought it was a symlink, but `ls -l` doesn't list it as a symlink, so either it is a hard link or some other sort of trickery.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas after Xcode is installed it should just be available... but you can also reference the file directly.... `man
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/share/man/man1/clang.1`

Comment: Thanks! I wasn't finding it because that path wasn't in my `MANPATH`. It's not listed in either `/etc/manpaths` or in `/etc/manpaths.d`. So how does your system find it? Or do you just explicitly add it to your `MANPATH` yourself?

Comment: if you either install the command line tools (older versions), or just install and use the newer Xcode it *should* be automagical

Comment: I've figured out that if `MANPATH` is unset, then it works. Obviously if one explicitly sets `MANPATH` in one's `.profile` (and it doesn't include the path leading to `clang.1`) then it won't work. Do you know how `man` is told what paths to use when `MANPATH` is unset?

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas read 'man man' section **SEARCH PATH FOR MANUAL PAGES**

Comment: I read it and looked at `/etc/man.conf`. Nothing is says explains how it finds a man page buried deep inside the Xcode bundle; yet it does.

Comment: yeah it looks like it is hard coded magic... try `man -d clang`

Answer (score 5):

This may be old and doesn't quite answers your concrete question, but I found myself in the same problem with Kali Linux and I solved it with this command, maybe is useful for someone:

```
apt install gcc-doc
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at how you set `MANPATH` in your `.profile`.  Instead of, e.g.,

```
export MANPATH=/opt/local/man:/usr/local/man
```

you should do

```
export MANPATH="/opt/local/man:/usr/local/man:$MANPATH"
```

And then (breathe) open a new Terminal window.

This way your `.profile` isn't wiping out (or reflecting an old version of) the system's way of setting `MANPATH`, which is modified when you install (or reinstall) Xcode.

Answer (score 1):

I use High Sierra with g++ 7.2 port. Setting MANPATH environment to  **/opt/local/man** (or to **/opt/local/man/man1** where **g++.gz** is found) did not work. So, after ensuring that the soft link **g++.gz** points to **g++-mp-7.1.gz** (there was not a **g++-mp-7.2.gz** in the man1 directory though g++7.2 is my version), I always use the command:

```
man /opt/local/share/man/man1/g++.gz
```

that never fails. You can store an alias for this in your **.profile**, if you are frequently using the **man** command for g++.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone who stumbles upon this currently (like I did), I found that I needed to locate my version of `gcc` (which I had installed with `brew`). This is annoying when `gcc --version` gives the `clang` version instead! To find the correct `gcc` version, run

```
$ ls /usr/local/opt/gcc/bin | grep gcc
gcc-10
gcc-ar-10
gcc-nm-10
...
```

So I had `gcc-10`. Whenever you wish to use `gcc` just replace it with `gcc-10`, e.g. `man gcc-10`. Of course you could write an alias for `gcc` to `gcc-10`, but this probably is not a great idea, as Xcode seems to rely on the `gcc --> clang` (hard?) link.