# gfortran manual does not exist although the installation was successful

Tags: macos, terminal, fortran

I installed gfortran in Mac OS X Yosemite following the instruction given in this [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/GFortranBinariesMacOS). So first, I installed command line tools. I did this by clicking the install button that is offered when I tried to run `$ make` command because this command requires command line tools, I think. Then install gfortran. There was no abnormal message during the installation. Moreover, I tried compiling some simple codes and they were successful. However, when I execute `$ man gfortran`, the terminal application said that the manual for gfortran does not exist.
Can someone find out what the reason is? 
Despite being able to compile some simple programs, I am worried if this actually indicates that certain part of the installation failed and prevents me to compile a certain more involved program in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some previous words on the same subject:

[How to fix "No manual entry for gcc"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684642/how-to-fix-no-manual-entry-for-gcc)

You can down load the pdf or HTML which (to me) seems more useful than man here: 
https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.6.4/gfortran.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The installer installs a link to gfortran in `/usr/local/bin`. This should echo in

```
$ ls -lth /usr/local/bin/gfortran
$ file /usr/local/bin/gfortran
```

Can you copy the output of these commands? If gfortran is there and is not found when typing

```
$ gfortran
```

at the command line, you must check your `PATH` environment variable (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_%28variable%29).

Comment: Thanks for your response.
The output of the first command is
`lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel    32B Nov 14 11:50 /usr/local/bin/gfortran -> /usr/local/gfortran/bin/gfortran`
While the second produces
`usr/local/bin/gfortran: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64`
Gfortran should be there since I am able to compile.

Comment: Hi,
The installer just provides the binary as a symbolik link https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link and does not "set" the rest of the environment.
If you have already a setting for MANPATH (i.e. `echo $MANPATH` does not return an empty line) you can set it as `export MANPATH=/usr/local/gfortran/share/man:$MANPATH`, else `export MANPATH=/usr/local/gfortran/share/man`).
The man command should find the help for gfortran afterwards. Typing `gfortran --help` is also useful.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to track down the man page on what I think is a properly installed gcc.

```
Mac: bin $ apropos gfortran
gfortran-7(1), gfortran(1) - GNU Fortran compiler
gfortran-9(1), gfortran(1) - GNU Fortran compiler
Mac: bin $ man gfortran-9
```

This gives the manual page for

```
Mac: man1 $ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Homebrew GCC 9.2.0_3) 9.2.0
```