# GCC- what does "-undefined dynamic_lookup" do?

Tags: gcc

I'm reading the open-source code for RBENV, and I came across [this line of code](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv/blob/c4395e58201966d9f90c12bd6b7342e389e7a4cb/src/Makefile.in#L22).  When I generated the Makefile using the `configure` script and ran `make`, I saw the following:

```
$ make
gcc -fno-common     -c -o realpath.o realpath.c
gcc -dynamiclib -dynamic -undefined dynamic_lookup   -o ../libexec/rbenv-realpath.dylib realpath.o
```

I wanted to know what each of these commands is doing, so I started Googling each of the flags.  I found many of them, but `-undefined dynamic_lookup` initially stumped me.  Eventually I found [this Github issue](https://github.com/ziglang/zig/issues/8016), which contained the following sentence:

> ...the option -undefined dynamic_lookup must be passed to the linker to indicate that unresolved symbols will be resolved at runtime.

This makes sense to me, given what I know about the purpose of this particular Makefile (it allows RBENV to use a faster, more performant version of the `realpath` program as a dynamic library).

However, I was unable to confirm this independently, since I don't see any official GCC docs which describe the `-undefined` flag or the `dynamic_lookup` option.  I Googled `gcc dynamic_lookup site:gnu.org`, but the only results which turned up were [Bugzilla tickets](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58056), [email threads about patches](https://gcc.gnu.org/legacy-ml/jit/2015-q3/msg00148.html), etc.  I also searched `man gcc` and `help gcc` in my terminal, but got `No manual entry for gcc` as a response.

Questions:

- Is the Github issue's description of `-undefined dynamic_lookup` correct?
- Am I going crazy, or is `-undefined dynamic_lookup` actually missing from the gcc docs?

Comment: `man gcc` ... `-undefined ... These options are passed to the Darwin linker.  The Darwin linker man page describes them in detail.`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I was getting the `No manual entry for gcc` error because "gcc isn't installed anymore by Xcode, it really installs clang and calls it gcc".  See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23684642/how-to-fix-no-manual-entry-for-gcc) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23688855/2143275) for more info.  Once I realized that, I Googled "man gcc" and found [the docs from man7.org](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/gcc.1.html).

As user @n.m. mentions in the comment above, the `-undefined` option (along with many others) is forwarded to the Darwin linker, therefore it is those docs that I should have been looking at.  Once I found [the Darwin linker docs](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/ld/), I found the info I was looking for:

> undefined < treatment >
>
> Specifies how undefined symbols are to be treated. Options are: error, warning, suppress, or dynamic_lookup.  The default is error.